# How to show results in entityreference autocomplete only after the user enters 5 characters

Tags: 7

I want to know if it's possible to show result of an entityreference autocomplete only when the user enters 5 or 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is create your own custom autocomplete (a good example is [here](https://www.webomelette.com/how-to-create-autocomplete-widget-drupal-7)) in your custom module. Then within your custom autocomplete function check if the submitted autocomplete string is 5-6 chars long then execute the search, like so (using the example from the tutorial above):

```
function demo_autocomplete($text) {
  if (strlen($text) > 5) {
  // execute your code here:
    $results = array();
    ... etc
    drupal_json_output($results);
  }
}
```